# Subtracting two tuples of same relation In Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a dataset like below.

```
(Bangalore, 30000, 15000)  
(Mumbai, 20000,10000)
```

My requirement is to find the difference between two fields ----- > $2-$1

i.e  I want output like below

```
(Bangalore, 15000)
(Mumbai, 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question.What is stopping you from doing $2-$1?

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:chararray,f2:int,f3:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,f3-f2; --This is equivalent to $0,$2-$1;
DUMP B;
```